# how to change bottom navigation view Active indicator color in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, bottomnavigationview

[Active indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lre6G.png)

How to change Active indicator(number 4 on the pic) color in xml file in andorid studio?